# Do function with timeout while togglebutton is pressed

Tags: javascript, timeout, do-while, togglebutton

I want to run a function with a timeout of 2000 ms. The function should just run while `toggleButton` is pressed.

When I run this function my CPU explodes:

```
do {
  setTimeout(function () {
    me.pushMockData();
  }, 2000);
}
while (liveButton.getPressed() != false);
```

Comment: Why are you using a do/while loop? Just check `getPressed` within the timeout function. Otherwise you're creating a very large stack of timeout functions.

Comment: Can you catch the event when it's pressed? If so, set new timeout after 'onPress' event and clear it (using clearTimeout ) on 'onRelease' event

Comment: Yeah, that's better, you're right.. But it doesn't fix the problem. My CPU explodes like before. The timeout doesn't work fine, I guess. It fires the pushMockData function continously without a timeout of 2 seconds.

Comment: @MarvinRügheimer i added an example if you don't mind to check. I see you found a solution, but anyway, i hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CPU explode because you create Timeout again, again and again really fast in your loop when button is pressed. If you want to run your function every 2 second :

- You should test if the the button is pressed.
- Use `setInterval`
- Inside `setInterval`, check if the button is still pressed, if not, `clearInterval`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

If you just want to active your function 2 second later, use `setTimeout` inside if.

Comment: Using `setInterval` seems like a bad idea as it has a tendency to speed up. Plus it seems like a lot more work when `setTimeout` could just be used.

Comment: You mean like that:

setInterval(function () {
                if (liveButton.getPressed() != false) {
                    me.pushMockData();
                }
                else {
                    clearInterval();
                }
            }, 2000);

Comment: Probably something like : ```var interval = setInterval(function () { if (liveButton.getPressed() != false) { me.pushMockData(); } else { clearInterval(interval); } }, 2000);``` inside an onclick listener of your liveButton

Only if you need to run code every 2 second, if not, use setTimeoout in an if statement.

Comment: You're welcome :) Try to be clear in your question, because it wasn't clear you needed it to run every 2 second, i just guess it with code ^^

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are constantly calling the `setTimeout` function in the while loop.

```
var timeout;

if (liveButton.getPressed())
{
    if (typeof timeout !== 'undefined') {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                      me.pushMockData();
                  }, 2000);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

}
```

Comment: That works better, thanks. But how can I run the timeout function until the button is pressed again?

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this all wrong, keep things simple and attach an event listener to the button and call setTimeout then.

**HTML**

```
<button id="my_button">Click Me</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('my_button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert('Clicked!');
    }, 2000);
});
```

**JSFiddle**

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3t5ne9ym/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can catch the onPress and onRelease event, it would be better if you do following

```
onPress
var myTimeout = setTimeout( ... , 2000 )

onRelease
clearTimeout(myTimeout)
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/jfefL4oo/1/